# How does Geoffrey Hinton's Capsule Networks work?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

Last week, Geoffrey Hinton and his team published [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829) that introduced a completely new type of neural network based on capsules. But I still don't understand the architecture and mechanism of work. Can someone explain in simple words how it works?

Comment: See here: 
https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/whats-the-main-concept-behind-capsule-networks/4438#4438

Answer (score 2):

One of the major advantages of Convolutional neural networks is their **invariance** to translation. However this invariance comes with a price and that is, it does not consider how different features are related to each other. For example, if we have a picture of a face CNN will have difficulties distinguishing relationship between mouth feature and nose features. Max pooling layers are the main reason for this effect. Because when we use max pooling layers, we lose the precise locations of the mouth and noise and we cannot say how they are related to each other.


Capsules try to keep the advantage of CNN and fix this drawback in two ways;

1. Invariance: quoting from this [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/transauto6.pdf)

> When the capsule is working properly, the probability of the visual
>   entity being present is locally invariant – it does not change as the
>   entity moves over the manifold of possible appearances within the
>   limited domain covered by the capsule.

In other words, capsule takes into account the existence of the the specific feature that we are looking for like mouth or nose. This property makes sure that capsules are translation invariant the same that CNNs are.

2. Equivariance: instead of making the feature translation **invariance**, capsule will make it translation-equivariant or viewpoint-equivariant. In other words, as the feature moves and changes its position in the image, feature vector representation will also change in the same way which makes it equivariant. This property of capsules tries to solve the drawback of max pooling layers that I mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the feature space of CNNs are represented as the scalars which do not represent the accurate positional features of the information. Furthermore the pooling strategy in CNNs eliminate the usage of important sclar features within a region, highlighting a given significant feature of a region. Capsule network is designed to mitigate those issues considering the vector representation of the features which could capture the positional context of the feature representation while mapping child-parent relationship effectively through dynamic routing strategy.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, typical networks use scaler weights as connections between neurons. In capsule net, weights are matrices as there are capsules with higher dimensions instead of neurons.